How to track Shopify videos in GTM?
Can someone help me out with this? I can only track click on videos on Desktop view. If I switch to responsive/smartphone view, not even clicks like on Desktop. I need to track everything like for YouTube videos: play/pause, duration watched in percent, video completed.
I managed to track clicks on smartphones by implementing event listeners, but it caused another problems, so I had to pause that implementation. I tried googling, but I couldn't find anything.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
